# Installing a limit switch to a small winch

Tags: switches, current-limiting

[image]

I need help with installing a limit switch to a small dc winch that has remote controls. I need to stop the winch from going one direction while allowing it to still function in opposite direction. I've included the schematic that came with winch.

Comment: What is the question? "I need help" is just way too broad. By the way, is Bule meant to be Blue? I would get a different switch just because the schematic revisor is not to be trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use normally-closed limit switches in series with the black and blue wires leading to the direction control switch. This way, the limit switch only stops one direction without interrupting the other direction.

For example, assuming the black wire runs the motor forward, connect the forward limit switch in series with it.

Comment: So I would wire limit switch in series on black wire before it enters relay at pin 85 or blue wire before pin 86 depending which one is the direction I want to control?

Comment: @racefan94 Correct